# Compare data in two Excel sheets to find the difference(s)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel sheets, similar content, but different order.

sheet1

```
   colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF 
r1  1   |  11  |  111 |   a  |  aa  | aaa
r2  2   |  22  |  222 |   b  |  bb  | bbb 
r3  3   |  33  |  333 |   c  |  cc  | ccc 
r4  4   |  44  |  444 |   d  |  dd  | ddd 
r5  5   |  55  |  555 |   e  |  ee  | eee 
r6  6   |  66  |  666 |   f  |  ff  | fff
```

sheet2

```
   colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF | colG
r1  1   |  11  |  111 |   a  |  aa  | aaa  | aaaa
r2  3   |  33  |  333 |   c  |  cc  | ccc  | cccc
r3  6   |  66  |  666 |   f  |  ff  | fff  | ffff
r4  2   |  22  |  222 |   b  |  BB  | BBB  | bbbb
r5  4   |  44  |  444 |   d  |  dd  | ddd  | dddd
r6  5   |  55  |  555 |   e  |  ee  | eee  | eeee
```

For these two sheets, colA is like the primary key of a table in DB, they are unique, I want to compare two rows with same colA data, but colG which is not in sheet1 will not be considered.

I want to add a new column in sheet2:

```
   colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF | colG | colH
r1  1   |  11  |  111 |   a  |  aa  | aaa  | aaaa | True
r3  3   |  33  |  333 |   c  |  cc  | ccc  | cccc | True
r6  6   |  66  |  666 |   f  |  ff  | fff  | ffff | True
r2  2   |  22  |  222 |   b  |  BB  | BBB  | bbbb | False
r4  4   |  44  |  444 |   d  |  dd  | ddd  | dddd | True
r5  5   |  55  |  555 |   e  |  ee  | eee  | eeee | True
```

What can I do with formula or macro?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would recommend starting with `COUNTIFS`, and check if it is `>0`.  (You may also want to take the [tour], and review the [ask] page)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am new to excel, so I am not familiar with the functions, I was looking at VLOOKUP, MATCH, INDEX and ROW, but it seems not easy to write a formula I want, I have too many data in one row, I am trying to find an easier way, I will look at COUNTIFS then, thanks again for your advicement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through and add true/false as your output (assuming your data is in the same place just on different sheets:

```vb
Sub ConditionCheck()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim numberCols as long
    Dim myFlag as Boolean
    Dim lRow as Long
    Dim wsSheet1 as Worksheet, wsSheet2 as Worksheet
   'edit the sheets as per the name of yours
    Set wsSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

   'assuming table you want output on is on sheet 2
   lRow = wsSheet2.Range("A" & wsSheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   'number of columns in your table (6 in example above)
   numberCols = 6
   'iterate vertically through table
   For i = 1 to lRow
       'iterate horizontally through table to compare values
       For j = 1 to numberCols
           'compare values to check for differences
           'if dont match then set flag to false
           If wsSheet1.Cells(i,j).Value <> wsSheet2.Cells(i,j).Value Then
               myFlag = False
               Exit For
           Else
               myFlag = True
           End If
       Next j

       'once the full condition has been checked we insert result
       If myFlag = True Then
           wsSheet2.Cells(i,(numberCols+1)).Value = "True"
       Else
           wsSheet2.Cells(i,(numberCols+1)).Value = "False"
       End If
       'reset flag
       myFlag = False
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It's writing TRUE to H1 and FALSE to B2:B6. Use <!-- language: lang-vb --> before the code for it not to be all in black.

Comment: a) It usually complies to pick up VBA. b) thank you for pointing that out. Simply used `j` incorrectly. Was meant to use `numberCols` to insert the values. Have edited. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it does not work for my file.

Comment: @Sampire what is happening? What error are you getting? This works in my file.

Comment: @Dean nothing happens and no feedback nor error message given to me in my file, I do not know why, so I cannot track the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Compare Data

Carefully adjust the values in the constants (Const) section to fit your needs.

```vb
Sub CompareData()

    Const cSrc As Variant = "Sheet1"    ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSrcChecks As String = "B:F"  ' Source Check Columns Address
    Const cSrcCrit As Variant = "A"     ' Source Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cSrcFR As Long = 1            ' Source First Row Number
    Const cTgt As Variant = "Sheet2"    ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cTgtChecks As String = "B:F"  ' Target Check Columns Address
    Const cTgtCrit As Variant = "A"     ' Target Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cRes As Variant = "H"         ' Result Column Letter/Number
    Const cTgtFR As Long = 1            ' Target First Row Number
    Const cYes As Variant = "True"      ' Yes String
    Const cNo As Variant = "False"      ' No String
    Const cNot As Variant = "Not Found" ' Not Found String
    Const cEmpty As Variant = "Empty"   ' Empty String

    Dim vntSrcC As Variant  ' Source Criteria Array
    Dim vntTgtC As Variant  ' Target Criteria Array
    Dim vntS As Variant     ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant     ' Target Array
    Dim vntR As Variant     ' Result Array
    Dim varTgt As Variant   ' Current Value (in Target Criteria Array)
    Dim NorSrc As Long      ' Source Number of Rows
    Dim NorTgt As Long      ' Target Number of Rows
    Dim Noc As Long         ' Source/Target Number of Columns
    Dim Lur As Long         ' Source/Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long           ' Target/Criteria/Result Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long           ' Source/Target Array Columns Counter
    Dim k As Long           ' Source/Criteria Array Row Counter

    ' In Source Worksheet (Check Columns)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSrc).Columns(cSrcChecks)
        ' Calculate (count) Source/Target Number of Columns.
        Noc = .Columns.Count
        ' Calculate Source Last Used Row Number.
        Lur = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        ' Calculate Source Number of Rows.
        NorSrc = Lur - cSrcFR + 1
        ' Calculate Source Criteria Range.
        ' Copy Source Criteria Range to Source Criteria Array.
        vntSrcC = .Worksheet.Columns(cSrcCrit) _
                .Resize(NorSrc).Offset(cSrcFR - 1)
        ' Calculate Source Range.
        ' Copy Source Range to Source Array.
        vntS = .Resize(NorSrc, Noc).Offset(cSrcFR - 1)
    End With

    ' In Target Worksheet (Check Columns)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTgt).Columns(cTgtChecks)
        ' Check if Target Number of Columns is euqal to Source Number of
        ' Columns.
        If .Columns.Count <> Noc Then
            MsgBox "The number of Check Columns NOT equal. Adjust Source " _
                    & "Check Columns (cSrcChecks) and Target Check Columns " _
                    & "(cTgtChecks) to have an equal number of columns.", _
                    vbCritical, "Check Columns Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Calculate Target Last Used Row Number.
        Lur = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        ' Calculate Target Number of Rows.
        NorTgt = Lur - cTgtFR + 1
        ' Calculate Target Criteria Range.
        ' Copy Target Criteria Range to Target Criteria Array.
        vntTgtC = .Worksheet.Columns(cTgtCrit) _
                .Resize(NorTgt).Offset(cTgtFR - 1)
        ' Calculate Target Range.
        ' Copy Target Range to Target Array.
        vntT = .Resize(NorTgt, Noc).Offset(cTgtFR - 1)
    End With

    ' Resize Result Array to rows of Target Array and one column.
    ReDim vntR(1 To NorTgt, 1 To 1)

    ' Loop through rows of Target Criteria Array.
    For i = 1 To NorTgt
        ' Write current value in Target Criteria Array to Current Value.
        varTgt = vntTgtC(i, 1)
        ' Check if Current Value is not empty.
        If varTgt <> "" Then  ' NOT empty (<>"").
            ' Check if Match function produces an error.
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(varTgt, vntSrcC, 0)) Then ' FOUND.
                ' Write position of found match to Source/Criteria Array
                ' Row Counter.
                k = Application.Match(varTgt, vntSrcC, 0)
                ' Loop through columns of Source/Target Array.
                For j = 1 To Noc
                    ' Check if values in Source and Target Array are NOT equal.
                    If vntS(k, j) <> vntT(i, j) Then Exit For
                Next
                ' VBA Help: ...For counter = start To end...
                ' Use the 'For Next Trick' to determine if all values were
                ' equal i.e. if counter is by one greater than end, the loop
                ' was NOT interrupted i.e. no value is NOT equal, i.e. all
                ' values are equal.
                If j = Noc + 1 Then   ' EQUAL.
                    vntR(i, 1) = cYes
                  Else                ' NOT equal.
                    vntR(i, 1) = cNo
                End If
              Else                    ' NOT found.
                vntR(i, 1) = cNot
            End If
          Else                        ' EMPTY (="").
            vntR(i, 1) = cEmpty
        End If
    Next

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTgt).Columns(cRes)
        ' Calculate Result Range.
        ' Copy Result Array to Result Range.
        .Resize(NorTgt).Offset(cTgtFR - 1) = vntR
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my file, I'll check to learn more about the code then.